# How to make Doctrine Migrations adding quotes to table names?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

I want to use Doctrine Migrations with existing database. Table names in this database has a dash, for example: `calendar-history`

I use `doctrine:mapping:import` command to create entities from database and it works well. Then I want to create first migration, so I use `doctrine:migrations:diff`. And then I have a problem because it creates queries without quotes, like:

`ALTER TABLE calendar-history DROP FOREIGN KEY calendar-history_ibfk_2`

I've tried to:

1. Add quotes to entity definition: `` @ORM\Table(name="`calendar-history`", ``
2. Add a custom QuoteStrategy class

... and it works only with queries in down() method. The queries in up() method in the migration still are without quotes.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the backticks?

Comment: @AmeliaMagee yes but it doesn't help.

Comment: Doctrine does not support back ticking table names.  It was a basic design choice.  For all intents and purposes, you will need to use a schema that does not require back ticks or use a different ORM.